# HCI Bluetooth snoop log creates an empty log file

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, reverse-engineering, android-bluetooth, hci

Whenever I enable the "HCI Bluetooth snoop log" in the developer options, all I get is an empty 16 bytes log file (btsnoop_hci.log). I'm sure Bluetooth is communicating because my app is working properly.

I have Android 5.0.1 on a ZenFone 2 (without rooting).

EDIT:
I've also noticed that even if I enable the HCI Bluetooth logging option, when I execute 
`adb shell cat /etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf`
 BtSnoopLogOutput is always false.

EDIT2:
Even after rooting the device and manually setting BtSnoopLogOutput=true, the log remains empty

Answer (score 0):

As i tested in samsung galaxy s5(Not rooted)..
btsnoop_hcl.log was only getting generated after i restarted my machine.,it was showing data properly after restarting. You also can try restarting you phone so the data may get loaded to log file..

Comment: It doesn't work (it didn't work at the time actually, I've not tried it again lately) on my Zenfone 2